# Conky auto startup in Fedora 28

Tags: fedora, startup, conky

This is recurring question yet I cannot make one program (`conky`) to automatically start when GNOME 3 starts. In `~/.config/autostart` I have the following file:

```
cat ~/.config/autostart/conky.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=conky
Comment=A startup script for conky
Exec=~/bin/conky_startup
Terminal=true
```

`~/bin/conky_startup` is as follows:

```
cat ~/bin/conky_startup

#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/conky --pause 10 -c ~/conky/white_conky &
```

When I execute `~/bin/conky_startup` conky starts without any problem. However, at startup the script fails to execute conky. Why?

Answer (score 3):

I've found working [solution](https://chocosmith.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/gnome3-conky-autostart-fedora/).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Conky
GenericName=background monitor
Comment=Keep a background eye on your system
Exec=conky &
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=conky
Categories=System;
StartupNotify=false
Name[en_US]=conky
```